# Tensorflow.js Error "tfjsconverter.loadGraphModel is not a function"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, mobilenet

I would like to create an object recognition using the camera feed for dog breeds using tf.js.

I built an object recognition demo that works
https://codesandbox.io/s/tensorflowjs-real-time-object-detection-om12e?file=/src/index.js:0-27 but it uses the cocoSsd model that doesn't have dog breeds.

So I know that mobilenet model does have dog breeds and I found a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/o4l6pnlkzz (though it uses images upload rather than the camera feed).

When I tried to put the mobilenet model into the object detection example, I get the following error. "tfjsconverter.loadGraphModel is not a function".

https://codesandbox.io/s/tensorflowjs-real-time-object-detection-forked-6hxdb?file=/src/index.js:925-934

I imagine there's something wrong on line 31, but I can't figure it out.

If you know what I'm doing wrong, it would be really helpful for a few pointers.